# Encode protocol variables

Tags: ios, swift, codable, swift-protocols

suppose I have this protocol that provides a variable

```
protocol Drivable { 
    func drive()
    var maximumSpeed: Double
}

extension Drivable {
   public var maximumSpeed: Double { return 50.5}
}
```

and a concrete Encodable class that conforms to:

```
class Car: Drivable, Encodable {
    var manufacturer: String

    func drive() {
       print("Driving a car")
    } 
}
```

Trying to Encode a class  with `JSONEncoder().encode(myCar)` will result in `{"manufacturer:"Hyundai"}`, the encoder will not encode `maximumSpeed` provided by Protocol with a default value, only works when I implement encode and CodingKeys like:

```
class Car: Drivable, Encodable {
    var manufacturer: String

    func drive() {
       print("Driving a car")
    }

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       case manufacturer
       // Protocol Variable Here
       case maximumSpeed
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(manufacturer, forKey: .manufacturer)
      try container.encode(maximumSpeed, forKey: .maximumSpeed)
    }
}
```

I feel it's not a cool approach implementing the CodingKeys and encode every time a class conforms to Drivable Protocol. How can I provide a default CodingKeys and Encode for Variable Protocol?

Answer (score 0):

`JSONEncoder().encode()` works automatically with stored properties, not with computed one, so you need to add `maximumSpeed` property to your model:

```
class Car: Drivable, Encodable {
    var manufacturer: String
    var maximumSpeed: Double

    func drive() {
       print("Driving a car")
    } 
}
```